# Api Client Login Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I experienced problems when connecting my login to an API service, where in my system there are divisions into user categories, namely Admin and User, the problem that occurred was when entering USERNAME and PASSWORD in the login form and if the database contained the username & password then my system would take LEVEL from the same table to retrieve level data whether it is ADMIN or USER, but in the API service there is no JSON data in the form of LEVEL and ID_SESSION (I also need ID_SESSION from the same table)....

I've tried making some code, but I experienced an error when retrieving the session_id and level. So in my code below... which part or what method should I do to make it work?

I always get an error in the check_login function: Username dan Password Tidak Valid di API ini!

This is the JSON data in my API service:

> {"data":
> [{"stb":"000000","nmmhs":"ABCDFGHIJK","alm":"MARS","email":"abcdf@gmail.com","nohp":"07737773773"}]}

This is the code I made:

1. Controller Login.php :

```php
function index(){
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if ($this->input->post() && (strtolower($this->input->post('security_code')) == strtolower($this->session->userdata('mycaptcha')))) {
            $username = $this->input->post('a', TRUE);
            $password = $this->input->post('b', TRUE);

            $api_url = 'https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.ac.id/mhs.php?user=' . urlencode($username) . '&pass=' . urlencode($password) . '&api=010101';
            echo $api_url;
            $api_response = file_get_contents($api_url);
            $api_data = json_decode($api_response, true);

            if ($api_data && isset($api_data['data'][0]['stb']) && isset($api_data['data'][0]['nmmhs'])) {
                $username_api = $api_data['data'][0]['stb'];
                $password_api = $api_data['data'][0]['nmmhs'];

                $cek = $this->model_app->cek_login($username_api, $password_api, 'users');

                if ($cek) {
                    // Set session berdasarkan level dari digit ketiga
                    $level = (substr($username_api, 2, 1) === '1') ? 'mahasiswa' : 'admin';

                    $this->session->set_userdata('upload_image_file_manager', true);
                    $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                        'username' => $username_api,
                        'level' => $level,
                        'id_session' => $cek['id_session']
                    ));
                    echo 'redirect to administrator/home';
                   
                } else {
                    echo $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger"><center>Username dan Password Salah!!</center></div>');
                    echo 'redirect to administrator/home';
                   
                }
            } else {
                echo $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger"><center>Username dan Password Tidak Valid di API!</center></div>');
                echo 'redirect to administrator/home';
               
            }
        } else {
            echo $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger"><center>Security Code salah!</center></div>');
            echo 'redirect to administrator/home';
           
        }
    } else {
        if ($this->session->level != '') {
            echo 'redirect to administrator/home';
           
        } else {
            $this->load->helper('captcha');
            $vals = array(
                'img_path'   => './captcha/',
                'img_url'    => base_url() . 'captcha/',
                'font_size'     => 17,
                'img_width'  => '320',
                'img_height' => 33,
                'border' => 0,
                'word_length'   => 5,
                'expiration' => 7200
            );

            $cap = create_captcha($vals);
            $data['image'] = $cap['image'];
            $this->session->set_userdata('mycaptcha', $cap['word']);
            $data['title'] = 'Users &rsaquo; Log In';
            $this->load->view('administrator/view_login', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Login view code snippet :

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo"> 
    <a href="#"><b>USERS</b> Login</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body login-card-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
        <?php 
            echo $this->session->flashdata('message');
            echo form_open($this->uri->segment(1).'/index'); 
        ?>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name='a' placeholder="Username" required>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name='b' placeholder="Password" required>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <?php echo $image; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='security_code' placeholder="Security Code" required>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
            <a data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle='modal' href='#lupapass' data-target='#lupapass'>I forgot my password</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" name='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-card-body -->
  </div>
</div>
```

3. Function Login Cek :

```
public function cek_login($username, $password, $table)
{
    $api_url = 'https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.ac.id/mhs.php?user=' . urlencode($username) . '&pass=' . urlencode($password) . '&api=010101';
    $api_response = file_get_contents($api_url);
    $api_data = json_decode($api_response, true);

    if ($api_data && isset($api_data['data'][0]['stb']) && isset($api_data['data'][0]['nmmhs'])) {
        $username_api = $api_data['data'][0]['stb'];
        $password_api = $api_data['data'][0]['nmmhs'];

        // Tentukan level berdasarkan username
        $level = (substr($username_api, 2, 1) === '1') ? 'mahasiswa' : 'admin';

        // Buat id_session secara otomatis menggunakan uniqid()
        $id_session = uniqid();

        // Set data untuk session
        $data = array(
            'username' => $username_api,
            'level' => $level,
            'id_session' => $id_session
        );

        return $data;
    } else {
        // Jika data tidak valid di API, beri pesan bahwa login tidak berhasil
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger"><center>Username dan Password Tidak Valid di API ini!</center></div>');
        redirect($this->uri->segment(1) . '/index');
        return false;
    }
}
```

4. Function Home :

```
function home(){
        if ($this->session->level=='admin'){
          $this->template->load('administrator/template','administrator/include/view_home_admin');
        }else{
          $data['users'] = $this->model_app->view_where('users',array('username'=>$this->session->username))->row_array();
          $data['modul'] = $this->model_app->view_join_one('users','users_modul','id_session','id_umod','DESC');
          $this->template->load('administrator/template','administrator/include/view_home_users',$data);
        }
    }
```

I want to know how to trick my system so that the `level` and `id_session` are taken from the API or from my local database.